# How to add SQLite3 database authentication with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I add user name and password (authentication) for a SQLite3 database created with Python script?

I already find this is SQLite documentation:

```
 int sqlite3_user_authenticate(
     sqlite3 *db,           /* The database connection */
     const char *zUsername, /* Username */
     const char *aPW,       /* Password or credentials */
     int nPW                /* Number of bytes in aPW[] */
   );
```

but couldn't figure it out how to use it with my Python code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("E:\\Dev\Db\MyBooks.sqlite")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums
                  (title text, artist text, release_date text,
                   publisher text, media_type text)
               """)
```

Comment: Are you trying to authorize users connecting to the database or store users and passwords in the database?

Comment: I don't think the Python sqlite3 module supports the SQLite user authentication modification. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hi I am hoping to secure the database so only a user with correct `username` and `password` can connect to the database and run query against it. like SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: That documentation also says: "Activate the user authentication logic by including the
ext/userauth/userauth.c source code file in the build and
adding the -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION compile-time option.
The ext/userauth/sqlite3userauth.h header file is available to
applications to define the interface."